# What could be wrong with my premake5 script that it takes so long to build a solution

Tags: premake

I am using premake5 version 0.06 to generate a vs2012 project that contains 3000+ files in a directory tree that goes about 2 levels deep.

The project contains 6 configurations and 3 platforms.

It takes approximately 2 minutes to bake the configurations and then about 10 seconds to process the action and write out the solution and project files.

I am wondering if this is the expected time for this number of files or whether I can optimise my premake scripts to improve the bake times?

I make use of a number of overrides and I include my files by making use of wildcards.

```
    files {
        path.join(includeDir,"**.h"),
        path.join(includeDir,"**.inl"),

        path.join(srcDir,"**.h"),
        path.join(srcDir,"**.inl"),
        path.join(srcDir,"**.c"),
        path.join(srcDir,"**.cpp"),
    }
```

Is it better to put all options under one filter?
For convenience of setup I have options setup by different functions and so effectively list the same filter multiple times for different options e.g.

```
setupOption1 = function(args)
   filters( "platforms:win" )
        --set up option1
end

setupOption2 = function(args)
   filters( "platforms:win" )
      --set up option2
end

--with the project 
project("myProject")
   --global setup
   language    "C++"
   kind        "WindowedApp"

   --individual options
   setupOption1(args)
   setupOption2(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

That does sound a little long, but as this is still an alpha build performance isn't being as closely monitored right now. There is [an open pull request to reduce memory usage](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/275) that might help?

In general, fewer filters should help, but I would be surprised if it made a dramatic difference (unless you really have a *lot*).

Answer (score 0):

I found that using ** wildcards in a files filter slows the build right down.

```
filter {"files:**_win.cpp", "platforms:not win"}
    flags "ExcludeFromBuild"               

filter {"files:**_xone.cpp", "platforms:not xone"} 
    flags "ExcludeFromBuild"

filter {"files:**_ps4.cpp", "platforms:not ps4" }
    flags "ExcludeFromBuild"
```

If I comment out these filters, the configuration now takes about 30 seconds to build.